# How to format a partition with hfs+journalized filesystem?

Tags: 11.04, partitioning, format

I want to make a partition with hfs+journalized format. First I make a partition with command 'fdisk' and then I want to use command 'mkfs' to format the partition, but I can not find the hfs+journalized format, I can find hfs+ format only.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the -J flag:

```
mkfs.hfsplus -J [journal size] [other options]
```